# How to set up position movements for background nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

**How can I set up background animations only once and make them move forever?**

I'm developing a game using iOS Swift and SpriteKit. I have a lot of background nodes in my game, like clouds, mountains, etc.

Currently I'm moving clouds around the scene like this. This code is in the `override func update`:

```
        if self.cloud01.position.x < 0 - self.cloud01.size.width {
            self.cloud01.position.x = self.frame.size.width + (self.cloud01.size.width / 2)
        } else {
            self.cloud01.position.x -= 0.5
        }
```

Whenever the cloud moves out of the scene (left side) it will be reset to the right side and move again.

I want to take all these if-statements out of the update function and set them up only once. I've tried this:

```
//This is in my didMoveToView
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.runBlock(backgroundAnimations)))

//It calls this function
func backgroundAnimations() {

        if self.cloud01.position.x < 0 - self.cloud01.size.width {
            self.cloud01.position.x = self.frame.size.width + (self.cloud01.size.width / 2)
        } else {
            self.cloud01.position.x -= 0.5
        }
}
```

**How can I set up background animations only once and make them move forever?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SKAction`s. Simply add this line when you initialize your clouds.

`world` - your clouds `parentNode` (probably you need to replace with `self`)

```
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.moveByX(-world.frame.size.width , y: 0, duration: 10.0),
        SKAction.moveByX(world.frame.size.width , y: 0, duration: 0),
    ])))
```